# Python - "Index Error" when I run program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing code for taking the second derivative but I'm getting an error. It's saying there's something wrong with the second derivative equation line. I don't understand what I'm going wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def d2(f,dx):
    df_dx = []
    for i in range(len(f)-1):
        df_dx.append(f[i+dx] - 2*f[i] + f[i-dx])/(dx*dx)

f = np.sin(np.linspace(0,5,50))
output = d2(f,0.1)
expected = np.cos(np.linspace(0,4.9,49))
diff = abs(output-expected)
plt.plot(diff)
```

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: `dx` is a float (0.1 in your example), so `i+dx` is a float and can't be used to index the array `f`. You probably need something like `(f[i+1] - 2*f[i] + f[i-1])/(dx*dx)`.

Comment: That gives me TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: I'm missing a return statement

Comment: Added to my answer. I also adjusted the expected case.

Comment: @Craig Getting the same TypeError with the return statement

Comment: The expression was missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code, one is that you are trying to index your array with a float value, the other is that you are not using `dx` to create your initial data set. The code below addresses both these:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def d2(f,dx):
    df_dx = []
    for i in range(1, len(f)-1): #start i at 1 so that i-1 is 0 on the first iteration
        df_dx.append((f[i+1] - 2*f[i] + f[i-1])/(dx*dx)) #add parenthesis around expression
    return df_dx

dx = 0.1 
x = np.arange(0, 5+dx, dx) # create an array that has a values spaced by dx
f = np.sin(x) 
output = d2(f,dx)
expected = -np.sin(x[1:-1]) #2nd derivative is missing first and last points from original array
diff = abs(output-expected)
plt.plot(x[1:-1], diff)
```

Comment: One more thing, the second derivative of `sin(x)` is `-sin(x)`, not `cos(x)`.

Comment: Perfect. Really appreciate your help.